# Gaining access to private beta questions through the API

Tags: bug, api, private-beta

I'm not sure how this site has done it, but [Column80](http://www.column80.com/?continue=y) appears to be able to load questions from private beta websites through the V2 API.

[Here is a link](http://www.column80.com/api.v2.php?a=puzzling) to the list of questions on Puzzling.SE. I only found this because one of our private beta questions was indexed, and I was researching an answer. It was the first result (yay!), but on the other hand, it was exposed.

Is this intentional? If so, what is Column80?

Comment: [Column 80 - Plain Text optimised Stack Exchange](http://stackapps.com/q/542)